# How to read multiple data types in a file line c++

Tags: c++, file

My code will write variables to a file as a backup system. When the user rerun the code, I need to copy the file data and save to variables.

```
John McClane, 31, 1.76
```

The file will always have a string, an integer and a double, in this order.
Is there a function to read the variables easily, considering that will always have the commas separating? Better to use txt or csv file type?

Comment: Look at using `std::getline()` for reading whole lines, as well as delimited strings, from any `std::istream`. Read a line from a `std::ifstream`, put the string into an `std::istringstream`, read substrings from it using `','` as the delimiter. Convert substrings to integers/floats using `operator>>` or `std::stoi()`/`std::stod()` as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Nice question for learning the `iostream` a little bit better.

Let us start at the beginning. You may have seen something like:

```
std::cout << value1 << ',' << value2 << ',' << value3 << '\n';
```

The secret is the overloaded operator `<<`, which may be implemented as:

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const SomeType& st)
```

And this operator is overlaoded for many many standard data types. One of the secrets, why it can be chained, is that it returns a reference to the given stream. (Please note, this function can also explitely called)

So, if you write:

```
std::cout << value;
```

then, it will write the value to `std::cout` and return a reference to the given stream `std::cout`. If we look at the chained call above, then after value1 will have been written, `std::cout` is returned. Then the new rest statement to work on, will be

```
std::cout << ',' << value2 << ',' << value3 << '\n';
```

It will then output the comman and again return `std::cout`. Result will be:

```
std::cout << value2 << ',' << value3 << '\n'; // then next
std::cout << ',' << value3 << '\n'; // then next
std::cout << value3 << '\n'; // then next
std::cout << '\n'; // then next
std::cout  // then next
```

You may now ask, why it is important that I list up the last line. That is, because both the `bool` operator and the `!` (not) operator for streams is overwritten. Please read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) and [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator!). So, if you use a stream in an a conditional context, like in an `if` or `for` or `while`. Therefore, after opening a stream, you can simply write: `if (stream)` and you know that there was no error.

If you want to read values in a loop, then you can write

```
while (filestream >> v1 >> v2 >> v3) {   . . .
```

then it will do all extractions as described above, and the rest statement will be `while(filestream)`. The bool operator of the stream will be called and checks, if everything is ok, or if their was a failure or and eof (end of file).

Next, it is important to understand the mechanisms of formatted and non-formatted operations. All the above was formatted. The extractor operator will convert the streams data into a value of your type. It will not read any white space, including the new line character '\n'. Before reading the next value, it will first skip all white spaces and read and convert the next value and not read the trailing whitespace.

Non-formatted input functions like `std::getline` will read a complete line, do not do any conversions and consume the last new line '\n' from the stream.

This causes many problems in understanding and is a source for many bugs.

R.g. If you have a transition from formatted input to non formatted input, then the following will happen. The last formatted input like in `std::cin >> value` will read the value and convert it. It will not read the new line character. This is still in the stream. And, a following call to `std::getline` will read until the newline character, which it will find immediately, as first character, as leftover from the previous formatted reading and hence do nothing.

Therefore, if there is a transition, from formatted to unformatted input, you need to get rid of the new line (or other white spaces). And for this we have a manipulator in the library. It is called `std::ws` and exactly does what we want. Please see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ws). It will discard leading whitespace from an input stream. Fine.

Then let us look at some example code now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

const std::string fileName{ "data.txt" };

int main() {

    // Open file and check, if it could be opened
    if (std::ifstream inputFileStream{ fileName }; inputFileStream) {

        // We want toread 3 values
        std::string name{};
        int iValue{};
        double dValue{};
        char comma{};

        // Read data from file, convert them to there data type and read until eof
        while (std::getline(inputFileStream >> std::ws, name, ',') >> iValue >> comma >> dValue) {

            // Show output
            std::cout << name << " --> " << iValue << " --> " << dValue << '\n';
        }
    } // Error message, if file could not be opened
    else std::cerr << "\nError:Could not open file '" << fileName << "'\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Please apply the know how from above. First `inputFileStream >> std::ws` will be called, which will return `inputFileStream`. Then `std::getline` will be called, which will return `inputFileStream`. Then `inputFileStream >> Name` will be called, which returns `inputFileStream` and so on and so on.

I hope,I could make some things more clear.